Player Camera doesn't get deactivated when calling a certain script
I am currently making a small project where the player is able to hide in a locker and under a table. I have it that when a player hides in a locker, the player object automatically disappears which is something, but whenever im interacting with the table that has a script attached to it. It doesnt seem to disappear. Rather it just stays stuck, this is really annoying because im trying to also get the player removed when hiding under a table. Could anyone help me out with this problem? Ive looked everywhere on how to solve this and i dont think the problem relies on the code itself. But i just had to ask it around.
This is the script for the table:
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TriggerTable : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private bool isHidingTable;
    [SerializeField] private bool canHideTable;
    [SerializeField] private Transform cameraTablePos;
    [SerializeField] private new Transform camera;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject player;
    [SerializeField] private Camera playerCamera;
    [SerializeField] private Camera tableCamera;

    void Start()
    {
        cameraTablePos = GameObject.Find("TablePosition").transform;
        player = GameObject.Find("Player");
        
        playerCamera = GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<Camera>();
        tableCamera = GameObject.Find("TableCamera").GetComponent<Camera>();

        playerCamera.enabled = true;
        tableCamera.enabled = false;
        
        tableCamera.transform.SetParent(null);
    }

    void switchToTableCam()
    {
        player.SetActive(false);
        playerCamera.enabled = false;
        tableCamera.enabled = true;
    }

    void switchToPlayerCam()
    {
        player.SetActive(true);
        tableCamera.enabled = false;
        playerCamera.enabled = true;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
    {
        if (collision.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            canHideTable = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider collision)
    {
        if (collision.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            canHideTable = false;   
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && canHideTable)
        {
            isHidingTable = !isHidingTable;
        }

        if (isHidingTable)
        {
            tableCamera.transform.SetParent(null);
            camera.parent = cameraTablePos;
            camera.position = cameraTablePos.position;
            switchToTableCam();
        }

        else
        {
            switchToPlayerCam();
        }
        
    }
}

This is the script for the locker:
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TriggerLockerDoor : MonoBehaviour
{
   [SerializeField] private bool isHidingLocker;
   [SerializeField] private bool canHideLocker;
   [SerializeField] private Transform cameraLockerPos;
   [SerializeField] private new Transform camera;
   [SerializeField] private GameObject player;
   [SerializeField] private Camera playerCamera;
   [SerializeField] private Camera lockerCamera;

   void Start()
   {
      cameraLockerPos = GameObject.Find("LockerPosition").transform;
      player = GameObject.Find("Player");
      
      playerCamera = GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<Camera>();
      lockerCamera = GameObject.Find("LockerCamera").GetComponent<Camera>();    
      
      playerCamera.enabled = true;
      lockerCamera.enabled = false;
      
      lockerCamera.transform.SetParent(null);
   }

   void switchToLockerCam()
   {
      playerCamera.enabled = false;
      lockerCamera.enabled = true;
   }
   
   private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)  
   {
      if (collision.CompareTag("Player"))
      {
         canHideLocker = true;
      }
   }
   
   private void OnTriggerExit(Collider collision)
   {
      if (collision.CompareTag("Player"))
      {
         canHideLocker = false;
      }
   }

   void Update()
   {
      if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && canHideLocker)
      {
         isHidingLocker = !isHidingLocker;
      }

      if (isHidingLocker)
      {
         lockerCamera.transform.SetParent(null);
         camera.parent = cameraLockerPos;
         player.SetActive(false);
         camera.position = cameraLockerPos.position;
         switchToLockerCam();
      }

      else
      {
         player.SetActive(true);
         lockerCamera.enabled = false;
         playerCamera.enabled = true;
      }
   }
   
}

Here is a video of my gamespace and the type of problem im facing.
[Link to the video of my gamespace1

You are setting the player camera to enabled every frame. You should only change it when you start or end hiding. Your locker and your table are running every frame, and it seems that you locker is running afterwards, so it's overriding any changes that the table made.
Also, is there any reason why you aren't just using a single script for both?
This seems much simpler anyways:
public class HidingPlace : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Camera hidingCamera;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject player;
    [SerializeField] private string playerTag = "Player";
    
    private Camera playerCamera; // Could also expose this with [SerializeField]
    private bool canHide;
    private bool isHiding;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // We are assuming the camera is a child of the player object
        playerCamera = player.GetComponentInChildren<Camera>();
        hidingCamera.enabled = false;
    }
    
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
    {
        // Only change canHide when we are walking around, not when already hiding
        if (isHiding) return;
        
        if (collider.CompareTag(playerTag))
        {
            canHide = true;
        }
    }
    
    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider collider)
    {
        // Only change canHide when we are walking around, not when already hiding
        if (isHiding) return;
        
        if (collider.CompareTag(playerTag))
        {
            canHide = false;
        }
    }
    
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && canHide)
        {
            hiding = !hiding;
            if (hiding)
            {
                player.SetActive(false);
                hidingCamera.enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                player.SetActive(true);
                hidingCamera.enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}


the reason why im using two seperate files, is mainly because they are two different models and it would be hard. And mainly because it was for me way better to read everything easily without repeating myself. Im going to take a look tomorrow on your given code btw. Ill let you know if it worked! Thank you :D

@heymasin the reason why im using two seperate files, is mainly because they are two different models and it would be hard .. tbh it is not that hard to simply attach another component to the models ^^ and  mainly because it was for me way better to read everything easily without repeating myself .. you pretty much repeated yourself .. your two scripts are basically a clone so whenever you change something you'd have to maintain it in both places .. even if they differ just a little bit it would still be better to have a common base class
